# LineRenderer on Mesh surface

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh

**Goal:** Render distance lines between two points on the surface of a mesh-based primitive (i.e. sphere, cube, etc).

[image: Lines drawn on surface of sphere]
**Current Solution:** Iteratively traverse distance line between two end points and "reverse" raycast through this point somehow. *Since the distance line directly connects both vertices through the mesh, the according points on the mesh surface are required.*

```
Ray ray = new Ray();
RaycastHit raycastHit;
ray.origin = posOnDistanceLine;
ray.direction = raycastNormal.normalized;
// Reverse ray since we can't raycast from inside the mesh
ray.origin = ray.GetPoint(1);
ray.direction = -ray.direction;
```

Lines are then drawn using Unity's `LineRenderer` which is being populated with positions of vertices whenever a change in normals (to previous raycast) is identified.

**Issues:**

- Horrible performance (as 100 rays are cast whenever the end points move).
- Solution doesn't always work and produces unexpected, jagged lines / points.

**Question:** 
Is there a better approach to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optimize the solution, you might need  to make a script for each primitive and utilize the primitive-specific math.

For example, instead of casting rays, you could simply get the radius of the mesh and put the line vertex at the `radius * directionFromCenter`.

Here is an example script:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class SurfaceLine : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private float pointsPerUnit;
    [SerializeField] private MeshFilter mesh;

    private Vector3 start;
    private Vector3 end;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    void Awake()
    {
        this.lineRenderer = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Left)
        {
            this.start = this.transform.InverseTransformPoint(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition);
            this.Render();
            return;
        }

        if(eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
        {
            this.end = this.transform.InverseTransformPoint(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition);
            this.Render();
        }
    }

    private void Render()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(this.end, this.start);

        var direction = (this.end - this.start).normalized;

        var numPoints = Mathf.FloorToInt(distance * this.pointsPerUnit);

        numPoints = Mathf.Max(numPoints, 2);

        this.lineRenderer.positionCount = numPoints;

        var positions = new Vector3[numPoints];

        var stepInDir = direction * (distance / (float)numPoints);

        for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
        {
            positions[i] = this.start + i * stepInDir;

            var dirFromCenter = positions[i] - this.mesh.mesh.bounds.center;

            positions[i] = this.mesh.mesh.bounds.center + dirFromCenter.normalized * (this.mesh.mesh.bounds.size.x / 2.0f);
        }

        positions[positions.Length - 1] = this.end;

        this.lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
    }
}
```

This seems to perform okay in an update loop too. The down side is of course that the solution is not generic. You will need a strategy per primitive.

Alternatively you can at least leverage the `pointsPerUnit` concept in the script to control the resolution of your line and stick with ray casting. I think the strange artefacts you are seeing is a result of too high point density. Making the points per unit of distance consistent may have better performance too.

Here is the result for the script above:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the insight! As you've noted yourself, this unfortunately only works for a single primitive, but as stated, I'll at least try to leverage the pointsPerUnit variable.